# ListView inside column does not expanded correctly

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, scroll

My window widget:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          globals.strings["add_event_title"],
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18,
            color: AppTheme.darkText,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Align(
              alignment: FractionalOffset.topLeft,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: AddEventWidget.withData(
                  categories: widget.categories,
                  geojson: widget.geojson,
                  address: widget.address,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Align(
              alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 16,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0)),
                        onPressed: () => {},
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        color: AppTheme.buttonConfirm,
                        child: Text(
                          globals.strings["add_event_button_confirm"],
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 16,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0)),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        color: AppTheme.buttonCancel,
                        child: Text(
                          globals.strings["add_event_button_cancel"],
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

`AddEventWidget` is actually ListBox to get conent scrollable if there's no room to show all controls. For testing, it's currently filled with Text widgets:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),

      ],
    );
  }
```

As a result, I'm indeed getting scrollable ListView, but with I want it to fit to remaining space (bottom buttons should not be scrollable, they need to be displayed at the bottom always). Current result:

[image]

Any ideas how to get the effect I need? Why my ListView is not expanded to fit remaining space without overlap bottom buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove Expanded from second child of the column, like this:

```
 Align(
          alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 16,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0)),
                    onPressed: () => {},
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'globals.strings["add_event_button_confirm"]',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Spacer(),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 16,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0)),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'globals.strings["add_event_button_cancel"]',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: It works, can you explain why do I need to remove Expanded in this case?

Comment: read ritik kumar srivastava's explanation, it's true what he says and that is the reason, but shrinkWrap = true is not neccessary and also it decrease performance.

Answer (score 2):

This is correctly rendered by flutter the problem is on your end.
You are using `two expanded widgets` inside a `Column` due to the `screen space` available is divided into `two equal parts`.

This leads to the `first expanded widget` to have half the size of the available column and hence the `ListView` reaches the max expend till the middle of the screen.

Two fix this and make `ListView` take up all the available space you can `remove expanded` widget `from` the second child i.e. the `Row`. And then in the `ListView property` shrinkWrap set it to `true`.

Code snippet here

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "add_event_title",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18,
            color: Colors.blue,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Align(
              alignment: FractionalOffset.topLeft,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child:ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
                    return Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
                  },
                  itemCount: 100,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 16,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0)),
                    onPressed: () => {},
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Text(
                      "confirm",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Spacer(),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 16,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0)),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    color: Colors.black45,
                    child: Text("cancel",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation